# How to update mySQL table row in which cell values are greater than n?

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I'm creating a CMS using PHP and as a begginer I ran into a simple problem. In the menu section, I use a table with this information:
ID ORDER NAME
ORDER describes in what place will the menu element appear in the menu.
While deleting a menu item, I want a script, that will automatically reduce the ORDER number by 1 for all the menu items, that have the order number greater than that deleted item.
Could anyone write that for me? Thank you

Comment: Firstly, SO wont write it for you, you will need to show what you have tried and got stuck on. Its the only way too learn. Secondly, why would you need to reduce this number? is there any reason the collection needs to have a sequentially numbered order?

Comment: Can u provide a better example of what you intent to do..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
UPDATE table_name
  SET order = order - 1
WHERE order > deleted_item_order_number
```

Answer (score 0):

that should be simple, you should refer to some php-mysql tutorial to strengthen your skills, otherwise you will end up creating not a very good cms.

here is your query:

```
update TABLE set order = order-1 where item_id > [your_deleter_item_id]
```